# Problem In Dual Booting

Tags: 14.10

I tried to install Ubuntu by dual booting it with windows 10 technical preview.
but when I started to install it I found that there was no option in Ubuntu 14.10 to dual boot it with windows 10.
so plz can anyone help to dualboot ubnutu 14.10 with windows 10 technical preview.

Comment: Can you choose an option like "Install Ubuntu alongside ......."?

Answer (score 0):

When dual booting windows, I like to partition my hard drive in windows before I attempt to install Ubuntu. Google "How to partition my hard drive on windows 10". This way when the Ubuntu install starts, it knows that your hard drive has free space to be able to install it "on the side". This might help that option show up in the Ubuntu installer window. When this happened to me, it was because it just wanted to install over windows because it didn't know it had free space and when I tried partitioning through Ubuntu it also just wanted to format everything first.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was take an already installed Ubuntu 14 environment and zero out a spare drive with dc3dd as `sudo dc3dd wipe=/dev/sdX` (where sdX= the drive I wanted to blank, in my case it was sdc). I disconnected the drives I didn't want Windows to see (call me paranoid). Then I booted up the Windows 10 Technical preview and installed it onto the spare drive. After insuring that Win10 was functioning to the best of it's ability, I shut down, reconnected my Ubuntu 14 drive and my home drive (I keep home on a separate drive, not necessary but a preference). Booted up Ubuntu, opened a terminal with CTRL-ALT-T and issued the command `sudo update-grub` Upon reboot the Windows environment was available for booting on the grub menu and worked fine.